# Scrapy not getting correct data with two tables on the page

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I've been using scrapy to scrape some data and one of the pages that I recently started to scrape has two tables compared to the normal one. I want to scrape the tables separately and the do have IDs. I've tried using a variety of paths (shown below) and I either end up with both tables scraped together, a blank dictionary of items, or scrapy not finding the path. The site is here:

http://www.faa.gov/data_research/commercial_space_data/licenses/

The crawler `response.xpath()` I tried with no return values are:

```
    //*[@id="DataTables_Table_0"]
    //*[@id="DataTables_Table_1"]
    /html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/table
    /html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table
```

Xpath that returns an empty Scrapy Item:

```
    (//table)[1]/tbody
```

And if I use `//tbody` and `//tr` as expected I end up with a list containing both tables.

My spider code:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
import items as spi      

class ActiveLaunchLicenseSpider(Spider):
    name = "faa_actlnchlic"
    allowed_domains = ['faa.gov']
    start_urls = ['http://www.faa.gov/data_research/commercial_space_data/licenses/']

    def parse(self, response):
        licenses = response.xpath('//tbody')
        for license in licenses:
            license_item = spi.ActiveLaunchLicenseScraperItem()
            license_item['license'] = license.xpath('//tr/td[1]/a').extract()
            license_item['company'] = license.xpath('//tr/td[2]').extract()
            license_item['vehicle'] = license.xpath('//tr/td[3]').extract()
            license_item['location'] = license.xpath('//tr/td[4]').extract()
            license_item['expiration'] = license.xpath('//tr/td[5]/span').extract()
            yield license_item
```

Can somebody help me understand either how my ID based paths were wrong (used Firebug to identify them) of a good way to select one table at a time?

Comment: Hmm possibly I'll try this in a little bit. Appreciate you pointing that out hadn't come across it in my searching for selector information related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code may help for scrap Data

```
import scrapy
from faa_gov.items import FaaGovItem
class faa_gov(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "faa_actlnchlic"
    allowed_domains = ['faa.gov']
    start_urls = ['http://www.faa.gov/data_research/commercial_space_data/licenses/']

    def parse(self, response):
        licenses = response.xpath("//caption[text()='Active Launch Licenses']/following-sibling::tbody[1]/tr")
        for license in licenses:
            license_item = FaaGovItem()
            license_item['license'] = license.xpath('.//td[1]/a').extract()
            license_item['company'] = license.xpath('.//td[2]').extract()
            license_item['vehicle'] = license.xpath('.//td[3]').extract()
            license_item['location'] = license.xpath('.//td[4]').extract()
            license_item['expiration'] = license.xpath('.//td[5]/span').extract()
            yield license_item
```

Comment: I modified this a little bit as the above only stored on row in the pipeline with my code. I updated the path to be `licenses = response.xpath("//caption[text()='Active Launch Licenses']/following-sibling::tbody[1]")` and the selectors to start at the tr level `license_item['license'] = license.xpath('.//tr/td[1]/a').extract()` which gave me all the rows in the table.